# algorithm for generating a random non-degenerate matrix over $[0,1 ]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science

I want to generate a random matrix $V\in [0,1]^{(n+1)\times n}$(not necessarily being binary ), such that for each row of $V$, there is at least one component is $1,$ and at least one component is $0$. Moreover. the constructed  $A:=[V,1^{n+1}]$(concatenate V with a column valued 1), is invertible.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "... $A:=[V,1]$ where $1 \in[0,1]^{n+1}$".

Comment: Are the entries of $V$ only $0$ and $1$ or any real number in between? If the latter then any random matrix has probability $1$ of being invertible.

Comment: The obvious algorithm is to generate the bits of the matrix independently at random, check if the resulting matrix satisfies your requirements, and iterate until it does. When $n$ is large, I suspect the probability of needing to iterate mant times is rather small. For invertibility alone, the probability of invertibility is $(1-\frac12)(1-\frac14)(1-\frac18)\cdots(1-\frac1{2^n}) > 0.288$.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks, but I mean the entries not necessarily being binary. And at the same time meet the conditions.

Comment: Ok, well if you want the entries to be real numbers between 0 and 1, but you also insist on having 0 and 1 themselves show up, then you're talking about probabilities that are neither purely discrete nor purely continuous. In this case, there is no particularly "canonical" probability distribution on the entries, so the possible answers are limitless. Without telling us what properties you want your distribution of "random matrices" to exhibit, there's no way we can guess which of the innumerable possibilities is going to satisfy you.